# Data munging with python: transforming string into rows

Tags: python, data-science, data-munging

I'm fairly new to python, and I need to perform some data munging. I want some advice on the best practice for this: libraries, modules, better code to implementment, or just direction.

So I have text file with data organised in the following format:

```
A:100 B:200 C:300

A:150 B:350 C:370
```

I.e. each line represents related data, 3 variables, named A/B/C. Each new line shows data regarding the same variables but related to another object.

So my data is in a text file, and I want to output it in the following format:

```
100 '\t' 150

200 '\t' 350

300 '\t' 370
```

I.e. rows of data for variables A, B and C, tabulated, such that I can export to a graphing toolkit (probably Origin Pro).

This is the code I've come up with thus far:

```
with open("example.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.replace(' ', '\n')
        line = line.split(':',  1)[-1]
        print line
```

This transforms the data into the following:

```
100
B:200
C:300

150
B:350
C:370
```

As the .split() is obviously only performed on each line prior to using .replace() to add new lines between the data. I feel like after I use .replace(), I need to start looping over the lines again to perform .split() or even just line[2:] iteratively, to remove the leading variable names - but then I can't think how I'm going to tabulate the data also for each line to create columns?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The indentation in your for-loop is incorrect. Please edit the question. This code would cause a SyntaxError.

Comment: `str.replace` and `str.split` do not modify the string in place. You have to assign the output for this to make any sense. e.g. `line = line.replace(' ', '\n')`

Comment: Correct on all those, have edited to make the code more syntactically correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you need some data structure to hold values for your variables. The most suitable one is a dictionary of lists:

```
d = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': []}
```

Then you go through the file, splitting each line into 'Name:value' items, then splitting these items on the `:` sign and storing values appriopriately:

```
with open("example.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        elements = line.rstrip().split()
        for e in elements:
            (name, value) = e.split(':')
            d[name].append(value)
```

and finally you output your data, one variable per row:

```
for k in sorted(d):
    print('\t'.join(d[k]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_infile, sep=' ', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: int(x[2:]))
df.to_csv(path_to_outfile, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

After you `import pandas` you can use `read_csv` function to load file into the dataframe with some additional arguments like:

- `sep` that is used to declare separator
- `header` that can be used to indicate that you don't have column names
- `names` that is used to assign names to columns

After that you can use `applymap` function on whole dataframe to remove variable names and colons.

Finally, you can use `to_csv` method to save your file to a desired location, again without `header` but this time without `index` as well because it will add index column by default.

As you can see, again you can use `sep` argument to declare new separator.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which makes it really easy:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file_path,sep=' ',header=None,names = ['A','B','C'])
output = df.apply(lambda x:x[.str.replace('^([A-Z]:)','')],axis=1).T
output.to_csv(file_path,sep='\t',header = False, index = False)
```

documentation:

[pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

[pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

[pandas.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)